# Route parameter not included in redirect

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

#### Premise

With react-router (v4) it doesn't seem to properly redirect with parameters.

```
<Redirect from="/people/person/:id" to="/people/:id"/>
```

If I visit `/people/person/123` though, it literally redirects to `/people/:id`.

---

#### Question(s)

Is this a feature that's missing from the latest version of react router or is my syntax incorrect? Is there another way of accomplishing this?

---

#### Other notes

- It is being used within a `<Switch>` tag.
- I've looked at the syntax here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect
- I saw some additional example syntax here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/1034

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original syntax will not work.

You must grab id from match.params.id see doc example https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route:

```
<Route path="/user/:username" component={User}/>

const User = ({ match }) => {
  return <h1>Hello {match.params.username}!</h1>
}
```

Yours would look like:

```
<Route path='/people/person/:id' render={props => (
  <Redirect to={`/people/${props.match.params.id}`} />
)}/>
```

Comment: This didn't quite work as-is for me, but I was able to do something similar and make it work. Thanks!

Comment: Is the `from` prop necessary in the `<Redirect />` tag?

Comment: Nope. I have never actually used the from prop. I left it on there to match your example, but it looks like it's extraneous here and only makes sense when the redirect is a child of a switch. Edited..

Comment: It is a child of a switch in my case, but I think that it only works with static redirects (at least right now). I think in the past it was a supported syntax by react router.